# Rellenar valores cero en DataFrame con valores medios agrupados por variables cualitativas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Tengo un tape con los precios de viviendas, superficie, repercusion, ciudad, etc...

Entre los valores hay algunos 0 en el precio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A traves de la funcion:

```
df_1.groupby(['city',])['reperc'].mean()
```

Saco el valor medio de la repercusion por cada ciudad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito rellenar los valores ceros con ese valor medio por ciudad.

buscando la solucion he intentado esto:

```
df_2_means = df_2.groupby(['city'])['reperc'].transform('mean')
df_2.loc[df_2['reperc'].isnull(),'reperc'] = df_2_means
```

no me da error pero siguen apareciendo el mismo número de 0 en el df_2

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataset` como texto, no como imagen así como el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que `df_2['reperc'].isnull()` no funciona como esperas. En la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) de la función lo tienes indicado. Esta función solo recoge los valores nan, pero tu estás intentando recuperar ceros con ella.
En tu caso, lo que quieres es seleccionar las filas cuya columna `reperc` sea 0, por lo que valdría con esto:

```
    df.loc[df['reperc'] == 0, 'reperc'] = df.groupby('city')['reperc'].transform('mean')
```

Otra solución sería reemplazar todos los 0 de la columna por `NaN`, de forma que en este caso sí que podrías llamar a `pd.isnull()` o `pd.isna()` como estabas haciendo antes.